# Password-protected file in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, passwords, archiving, password-protection

How do I store multiple files in an archive (like .zip/.rar) with password-protection on Mac OSX?

It has to be **a portable file** to keep on Dropbox or a USB-key.

Also, **the password-protection must be a standard**, so it can be passed between a Mac and Windows-PC.

The application should be free or downloadable via Mac App Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching around in frustration for a free alternative for a good free archiver **with a GUI** I finally found [Keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/).

[image: Keka Logo]

[Open source project on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keka/). Works like a charm with password-protected .7z-files.

[image: Keka GUI]

[Info off the webpage](http://www.kekaosx.com/):

> Keka is a free file archiver for Mac
>   OS X
>
> The main compression core is p7zip
>   (7-zip port)
>
> Compression formats supported:
>   **7z, Zip, Tar, Gzip, Bzip2**
>
> Extraction formats supported:
>   **RAR, 7z, Lzma, Zip, Tar, Gzip, Bzip2, ISO, EXE, CAB, PAX, ACE (PPC)**

Answer (score 5):

I believe this program will solve your issue:

[BetterZip 1.7.3](http://www.pure-mac.com/compen.html)

> BetterZip can **open, extract, and
>   create password protected zip files**
>   that are compatible with PKZip2 or
>   WinZip's AES256 encryption. Whenever
>   BetterZip needs a password for an
>   operation a panel will drop down and
>   ask for the password. BetterZip can
>   split archives into multiple volumes.
>   Add files and folders to existing
>   archives, update or rename files
>   already in the archive, move files
>   around within the archive, and delete
>   files and folders from an archive.
>   Create new folders inside the archive.
>   Easily search for files and folders by
>   name inside the archive.

Although apparently it costs $20, i was able to download it. Was not installed though, so it may require registration after a certain period.

I recommend you try the TrueCrypt answer also.

I also came across this [Tutorial](http://www.techiecorner.com/828/how-to-create-password-protected-zip-file-in-mac-os-x/) that does not appear to require any third party software.

All you have to do is open your **Terminal** and cd to the correct directory, then enter

```
$ zip -e myzipfile.zip file1.txt file2.txt
```

However, to open a passworded zip file on Mac you require third party software. I found [this tutorial](http://www.techiecorner.com/833/how-to-open-password-protected-zip-in-mac-os-x/) that used [Zipeg](http://www.zipeg.com/) to open the passworded zip.

I did have a friend try it though, and he used

```
$ unzip myzip.zip
```

And was prompted for the password.

The tutorial had mixed comments on it, so your version of OS X may vary on the results.

Comment: Added to my answer

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal:

```
zip -e zipname.zip file1.txt other.doc picture.jpg
```

Then enter a password. The default zip program on Mac couldn't open the file, but [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) could. You can do `unzip zipname.zip` in the terminal too, but it's a bit strange with the file paths (wants to save in the place the original files came from).

[From this page.](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=653030)